# unable to set cookie expiration date in javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

This is my first time using cookies and I want to set an expiration date of 1 day . With my code the cookie is set correctly  when I check dev tools but the expires tab says SESSION instead of 1 day from now .

My code  :

```
var createCookie= (title,store,price,pic) =>{
  var product = {
    called:title,
    soldAt:store,
    costs:price,
    image:pic,
  }
  var date = new Date();
  var exp = date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  console.log(exp); //huge number is probably seconds 
  var expires = '; expires='+exp;
  document.cookie =  'prod=' + JSON.stringify(product)+expires+'; path=/'; //added cookie 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date handling is incorrect, your date is returned in the number of seconds and you need a UTC string for cookies expiration dates, so I turned it back into a date object to get its UTC string

```
var date = new Date();
var expiresDate = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));
var expiresDateString = expiresDate.toUTCString();
```

In your last line

```
document.cookie =  'prod=' + JSON.stringify(product)+expires+'; path=/'; //added cookie
```

I believe you are missing a semicolon after your product and the word "expires="

try

```
document.cookie =  `prod=${JSON.stringify(product)}; expires=${expiresDateString}; path=/`; //added cookie
```

I used a JavaScript template string literal because it allows you to put variables and expressions inside of strings without all the manual concatenations with the "+"s and it helps you not miss characters here and there!

Comment: No I still see session instead of the date . Thank you for your time anyway

Comment: Sorry I forgot about the date, try it now!

Comment: Did not work the cookie is still stored for session . However If I exit localhost , close browser  and go back the cookie is still there

Comment: Interestingly for me when I'm on my Firefox profile "default-release" and do this, the cookie gets set to expiration "Session" but stays over sessions (last access is set to late in the evening yesterday somehow) and if I do the same in the same installation of Firefox in the profile "default" the cookie gets set with the exact same parameters according to the DevTools but gets deleted on browser restart. In UngoogledChromium it also gets deleted on browser restart. Setting the expiry date manually in DevTools makes it stay over sessions in both Firefox profiles.